# Fixing a webpage so it's non–scrollable. Specifically for mobile devices

Tags: iframe, mobile, static, scrollable, non-scrolling

I've just finished a website which is layering a webpage over an iframe. Everything is working fine on an Internet browser, yet on mobile when trying to scroll the background (the iframe, the content) it only scrolls the frontal fixed web icons. Is there anyway around this?

Specifically I thought if I could implement a non scrolling function on the front page it then scroll appropriately on the back page.

Does this sound like a feasible solution. If so could anyone assist in how to implement this?

thanks